# jquery Hide News Ticker if sharepoint annoucement list is empty

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013, news-ticker

I have a news ticker in my sharepoint 2013 plateforme who works well, but when I don't have news the banner still here empty, How can I hide it ? 
here's my code : [jquery.ticker.js](http://jsfiddle.net/bouyaImamura/Hhw4g/12/embedded/)
and :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
var soapEnv = "soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                <soapenv:Body> \  <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                        <listName>supported_applications</listName> \
                        <viewFields> \
                            <ViewFields> \
                               <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                               <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                           </ViewFields> \
                        </viewFields> \
                    </GetListItems> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
            </soapenv:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: "path to.../_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: processResult,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });
    });

    function processResult(xData, status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
              // var liHtml = $(this).attr('ows_ID') +":   " +$(this).attr('ows_Title')+'<br>'; var liHtml = "<li><a href='path to.../Lists/applications/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + $(this).attr('ows_ID') + "'>" + $(this).attr('ows_Title') + "</a></li>";
            $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);}); }
</script><ul id="tasksUL"/>
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hid the containing html element if count is empty.

```
 function processResult(xData, status) {

if( $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").length==0)
{
         $("#tasksUL").hide();
}

        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
              // var liHtml = $(this).attr('ows_ID') +":   " +$(this).attr('ows_Title')+'<br>'; var liHtml = "<li><a href='path to.../Lists/applications/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + $(this).attr('ows_ID') + "'>" + $(this).attr('ows_Title') + "</a></li>";
            $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);}); }
```

Comment: not working ... when I debug in the Browser, I find an error in the jquery.ticker.js : cannot read property 'style' of undefined and of null

Comment: Works when I put the Id of the webpart zone :  $("#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3").hide();